# Laravel tag search to return images that contain all tags

Tags: join, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, query-builder

I'm developing an application that lists images, and has multiple tags assigned to each image. I'd like to be able to find the images that are tagged with **all** of the tags being searched for.

#### `images` table

```
- id
- download_url
- image_width
- image_height
```

#### `tags` table

```
- id
- name
```

#### `image_tag` table

```
- id
- image_id
- tag_id
```

In my model for `Image`, I've got `belongsToMany('Tag')`, and in my model for `Tags`, I've got `belongsToMany('Image')`. This is all working as I hoped, so far.

However, my problem occurs when I try to search for images via their tags. I seem to be able to do an **or** search with the following code.

```
     $tags = explode(' ', $tag_text);

     $query = DB::table('images');
     $query->join('image_tag', 'images.id', '=', 'image_tag.image_id');
     $query->join('tags', 'tags.id', '=', 'image_tag.tag_id');
     foreach ($tags as $tag)
     {
          $query->orWhere('tags.name', '=', $tag);
     }

     $result = $query->get();
```

If I search for (for example) `nyc skyscraper`, I get a list of images that have the tag **nyc** or the tag **skyscraper**. However, I'd like to only show the images which have the tag **nyc** and the tag **skyscraper**.

I tried changing `$query->orWhere('tags.name', '=', $tag);` to `$query->where('tags.name', '=', $tag);`, but that then doesn't return any results (presumably because it's messing up the tag name search). The query Laravel is running `"select * from 'images' inner join 'image_tag' on 'images'.'id' = 'image_tag'.'image_id' inner join 'tags' on 'tags'.'id' = 'image_tag'.'tag_id' where 'tags'.'name' = ? and 'tags'.'name' = ?"` with the bindings `nyc` and `skyscraper`.

I wondered about doing an image search for each tag individually (which in the above example would return images with the tag **nyc** and then return images the tag **skyscraper**), and then pick out the images which occur in both results, but I'm not sure what the best way to implement this would be, and whether it's the most efficient way.

I suspect there's an easy way of doing this using the query builder that I'm currently missing!

What complicates it a little further (and currently doesn't work), is that as well as the tag search, I'd like to show images with (for example), a certain width. So after the tag code, I've included

```
    $query->where('image_width', '>', 1000);
```

which returns all images with a width over 1000 pixels, but only when I don't include the tag search code. If I do include the tag search code, it ignores the image width part of the search.

So, ideally, I'd like to return the images which are tagged **nyc** and are tagged **skyscraper**, and **are over 1000 pixels wide**.

Comment: I think you were very close with `$query->where('tags.name', '=', $tag);`.  What you can do after it's done running is `echo $query->toSql();` and it should show you the SQL it's trying to run and it would give you a better idea of what's wrong with it.

Comment: Thanks — I knew I'd forgotten to include something. I've now added the query.

Comment: Now that I see the query, I can see it's quite obvious why that wouldn't work.  Looks like we need to get a bit more creative, I'll post the answer in a second when I get it worked out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Manual count and `having` would work, but you can use simple `whereHas` instead:

```
// let it be array of tag ids:
$tagsIds;

$images = Image::whereHas('tags', function ($q) use ($tagsIds) {
   $q->whereIn('tags.id', $tagsIds);
}, '=', count($tagsIds))->get();
```

However mind that both mine and @user3158900's solutions will work only, when you have no duplicates on the pivot table. Using Eloquent's `attach` method on `BelongsToMany` relation may lead to such situation.

Comment: I like the simplicity of this answer — and it works! I'm wondering how to add additional (optional) parts to the query. Adding `->where('image_width', '<', 3000)->get();` to the end of that code gives me images which match the tags and the width, but because the width (and others) are optional, I'd like to add them later with `if` statements. I tried removing `get()` and then adding `$images->where('image_width', '<', 3000); $images->get();` but I get the error **Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string**. Can they be added like the query builder?

Comment: I'm not completely sure how I got it working, but it's now working how I wanted it to! Thanks.

Comment: Glad you worked it out. It's possible to chain it like you wanted, so `$query = ...; $query->where...; $query->orderBy...;` then somewhere else call `$query->get()`. You might have got that error because you forgot `get()` at the end.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk thanks, worked for me. you saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

Looking for images that has all the tags, we will probably need to count our results and group by the image_url after making our necessary joins.  This way, we can see how many tags each image matches and just get the images that match all the tags using the count because we know how many tags we have.

```
$tags = explode(' ', $tag_text);

 $images = DB::table('images')
  ->select(DB::raw('COUNT(*) AS `TheCount`, images.download_url'))
  ->join('image_tag', 'images.id', '=', 'image_tag.image_id')
  ->join('tags', 'tags.id', '=', 'image_tag.tag_id')
  ->whereIn('tags.id', $tags)
  ->groupBy('images.download_url')
  ->having('TheCount', count($tags))
  ->get();
```

If you need more than just the `download_url` for each image, you might need to change it up a bit.  I'd suggest instead of selecting and grouping by `download_url`, do it by the image's `id` and then you can set it up as a subselect and join it back up with the images table on the matching id's if that makes any sense.

Or just use `->lists('images.id')` to get the array of id's and make another query on the images table getting all images in that list of id's.

Comment: Great answer, although I do get an error. `Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '2 ?' at line 1 (SQL: select COUNT(*) AS 'TheCount', images.download_url from 'images' inner join 'image_tag' on 'images'.'id' = 'image_tag'.'image_id' inner join 'tags' on 'tags'.'id' = 'image_tag'.'tag_id' where 'tags'.'id' in (nyc, skyscraper) group by 'images'.'download_url' having 'TheCount' 2 )` Any idea what might be the problem?