# Laravel Searching with hasMany

Tags: php, search, laravel, eloquent

I have a Job model that can have many products.

```
Job.php
class Job extends Eloquent
{
    ....
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Products');
    }
    ....
}
```

And now I want the user to have the ability to search jobs by products.
The form to search the products:

```
job.search.blade.php
....
<div class="form-group required has-feedback products displayed">
    {{ Form::label('product_id', 'Product', array('class' => 'control-label')) }}
    {{ Form::select('product_id', Product::product_select(), Input::old('product_id'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'required' => 'required')) }}
    <span id="add_product_button" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign form-control-feedback"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group products hidden">
    {{ Form::label('product_id_2', 'Product #2', array('class' => 'control-label')) }}
    {{ Form::select('product_id_2', Product::product_select(), Input::old('product_id_2'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'required' => 'required')) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group products hidden">
    {{ Form::label('product_id_3', 'Product #3', array('class' => 'control-label')) }}
    {{ Form::select('product_id_3', Product::product_select(), Input::old('product_id_3'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'required' => 'required')) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group products hidden">
    {{ Form::label('product_id_4', 'Product #4', array('class' => 'control-label')) }}
    {{ Form::select('product_id_4', Product::product_select(), Input::old('product_id_4'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'required' => 'required')) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group products hidden">
    {{ Form::label('product_id_5', 'Product #5', array('class' => 'control-label')) }}
    {{ Form::select('product_id_5', Product::product_select(), Input::old('product_id_5'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'required' => 'required')) }}
</div>
....
```

In the JobController, with an instantiated variable:

```
$query = Job::orderBy('job_id', 'DESC');
```

How can I get products which the user has stated?

My attempt is getting close but I've been stuck for a while now.

```
JobController.php
....
if (Input::has('product_id') && Input::get('product_id') != 0)
{
    $query->with(array('products' => function($products)
    {
        $products->where('product_id', '=', Input::get('product_id'));
    }));
}
$jobs = $query->paginate(15);
....
```

**Edit: Solved**

I apparently couldn't use 'with' for search so I had to use SQL joins.
http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=13238

So for the searching with hasMany(),

```
if (Input::has('product_id') && Input::get('product_id') != 0)
{
    $query->where('inventory.product_id', '=', Input::get('product_id'));
}

if (Input::has('product_id_2') && Input::get('product_id_2') != 0)
{
    $query->leftJoin('inventory AS inventory_2', 'inventory_2.job_id', '=', 'jobs.id');
    $query->where('inventory_2.product_id', '=', Input::get('product_id_2'));
}

if (Input::has('product_id_3') && Input::get('product_id_3') != 0)
{
    $query->leftJoin('inventory AS inventory_3', 'inventory_3.job_id', '=', 'jobs.id');
    $query->where('inventory_3.product_id', '=', Input::get('product_id_3'));
}

if (Input::has('product_id_4') && Input::get('product_id_4') != 0)
{
    $query->leftJoin('inventory AS inventory_4', 'inventory_4.job_id', '=', 'jobs.id');
    $query->where('inventory_4.product_id', '=', Input::get('product_id_4'));
}

if (Input::has('product_id_5') && Input::get('product_id_5') != 0)
{
    $query->leftJoin('inventory AS inventory_5', 'inventory_5.job_id', '=', 'jobs.id');
    $query->where('inventory_5.product_id', '=', Input::get('product_id_5'));
}
```

If anyone could recommend me an efficient way for doing this, please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: What result do you want to retrieve?

Comment: @deczo Suppose there was a job #1 with three products: A, B, and C. There was another job #2 with two products, A and B. Now, they want to search for jobs with products; A, B, C. So that only Job #1 would show up.

Comment: Then you need `whereIn` and `count`. This is exactly what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24704119/laravel-tag-search-to-return-images-that-contain-all-tags#answer-24706347

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$products; // array of ids from the form

$jobs = Job::whereHas('products', function ($q) use ($products) {
   $q->whereIn('products.id', $products);
}, '=', count($products))->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `whereIn` method:

```
$query->with(array('products' => function($query)
{
    $productIds = Input::only('product_id', 'product_id_2', 'product_id_3');

    $query->whereIn('product_id', $productIds);
}));
```

You should probably use an array of product ids instead of numbering them, but that's a discussion for another day.

Comment: Quick question: What's the difference between `whereIn` v.s. `whereId` in the example above? Wouldn't `whereId($productIds)` do the same thing?

Comment: @JosephSilber Thank you, I will use an array instead of product_id_n to denote multiple products. I totally forgot about sending arrays through HTML form.

Comment: @Kousha - Nope. `whereId($foo)` is equivalent to `where('id', '=', $foo)`