# Merge two eloquent collections in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a system that allows users to create projects and assign tasks.  Now I am trying to scope a view to show all projects created by or assigned to the current user.  I have many to many relationships set up with three tables `users`, `projects` and `project_user`.  Where the projects table has a column `user_id` for who "owns" it.

I tried using the [merge method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-merge) for collections based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30522528/how-to-merge-two-eloquent-collections)  but I cant get it to work.

```
$projects = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection();

$userProjects = Project::where(array('company_id' => Auth::user()->company_id, 'user_id' => Auth::user()->id))
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
        ->get();


//foreach($userProjects as $up){
    $projects = $projects->merge($userProjects);
//}

$assignedProjects = User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->with('project')->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get();

foreach($assignedProjects as $assigned){
    $projects = $projects->merge($assigned->project);
}
dd($projects->all());
```

Then I tried converting to arrays and then manually created an object but that didnt quite work either and Im worried about resources.

```
$userProjects = Project::where(array('company_id' => Auth::user()->company_id, 'user_id' => Auth::user()->id))
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
        ->get()->toArray();
$assignedProjects = User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->with('project')->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get()->toArray();
$projects = array_merge((array) $userProjects, (array) $assignedProjects[0]['project']);
$cleaned = array_unique($projects, SORT_REGULAR);
$merge = array('projects' => (object) $cleaned);
$projects = (object) $merge;

dd($projects);
```

This is the user collection but I only need the project relations from this
[image]

This is the project collection
[image]

*The goal is to somehow get these to collections combined so I can access it from a view using $project->title (for example).*

**It was working fine when I just did it for projects the user "owned", now how do I get it to work to show both projects owned by user and projects assigned to user?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `whereHas` method:

```
$allUserProjects = Project::whereHas('users', function ($query) {
        // you can replace 'id' column by 'users.id' for clarity
        $query->where('id', Auth::user()->id); 
    })
    ->orWhere(function ($query) {
            $query->where('company_id', Auth::user()->company_id)
                  ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
    })
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
    ->get();
```

Comment: You are awesome, so much easier, thank you so much!  For anyone else looking for context of this here is the link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence