# How to Sort Data In a collection in Laravel

Tags: laravel, sorting, collections

I have the following relations
Transaction Table is the parent table for ETransaction and ATransaction and belongs to transactions table

```
$transactionA= Transaction::with('tAccount')->has('tAccount')->get();
$transactionE= Transaction::with('tExchange')->has('tExchange')->get();
$collection = collect([$transactionE,$transactionA]);
```

`$sorted = $collection->sortBy('created_at')` do not work for me

Comment: What kind of data are we talking about? What result did you get with what you tried, and what makes that result not suitable?

Comment: i tried $collection->sort() and $collection->sortBy(key)

Comment: I am trying to load data of  two tables from database and collect it to one collection i want to sort data inside a collection by created_at key  and dont give the suitable result

Comment: Then you need to combine the collections you have (`->get()` returns a `Collection`). You can't just call `collect()` on two collections and expect them to combine... Right now, you have a `Collection` of two collections, so calling `sort()` or `sortBy()` will have trouble working as you're expecting. Rethink your logic.

Comment: Which result do you get, and what makes it unsuitable?

Comment: It looks like your $collection property is a collection of two collections. That's 3 collections total, not 1 merged collection, which is presumably what @TimLewis points out as well

Comment: it shows data of  transactionE table on the top and transactionA table at the end like it show all records of transactionE table first and Then i start to show Data of second Table i want to show it on created_at key in both tables

Comment: @Stratadox then how to do deal with this problem any better suggestion please

Comment: I hope my answer results in what you're looking for, because your end-goal is still a bit unclear at this point.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem you encounter isn't necessarily about sorting, but about building up the initial collection.

Right now, you make two collections, `transactionA` and `transactionE`. You then initialize a third collection `collection` that contains both transactionA and transactionE.

You can think of this as transactionA being a box of records, and transactionE being another box of records. What you want is one big box of records, but the current code puts both boxes in another, bigger box. When sorting the bigger box, all you sort is the order in which the smaller boxes end up in the bigger box.

What you presumably want instead, is to merge the contents of both boxes and sort the ensemble. You can do so by [merging the two collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30522528/how-to-merge-two-eloquent-collections):

```
$collection = $transactionA->merge($transactionE);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you even need separate queries. Stratadox's answer shows how to query, merge and sort, but you can do that in a single query using `Eloquent`:

```
$collection = Transaction::with(["tAccount", "tExchange"])
->has("tAccount")
->orHas("tExchange")
->orderBy("created_at")
->get();
```

In a single query, this will look for all `Transaction` records that have either a `tAccount` or `tExchange` record associated, sort it by the `created_at` timestamp and return it in a single call. Pushing the logic to the `Collection` class can be inefficient, so let the database handle it when possible.

Comment: Upvoted because this is presumably the most performant solution. @Hewad: See my own answer for what went wrong initially, then apply this solution to get it working.

Comment: @Stratadox Upvoted yours too! Solution to the root cause of the problem should be the one that's accepted, I like to provide additional options that avoid the root problem. Cheers!

Comment: but i have some fields in tExchange which are not in tAccount it throws exception trying to get property of non object wiht orHas mehod

Comment: @Hewad Nowhere in your original question are you trying to access `$transaction->tAccount` or `$transaction->tExchange`. If you have a new problem, ask a new question.

Comment: no i have the field rate in tExchange that i don't have in tAccount but it throws exception

Comment: **The original question you asked was not how to access that**. If you have a new problem, ask a new question. That is how Stackoverflow works.