# How can I take all records from two table with an API in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

I am new here; I have a problem with an API in laravel.
I want to show all the records from two tables.
Table a : Flights;
Table b: Details_flights;

```
class FilterController extends Controller
{
    public function product(Request $request) {

        $flights= Flight::all();
        $details = Flights_detail::all();

        if(empty($flights)) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'length' => 0,
                'error' => 'No fly found',
                'results' => []
            ]);
        }else {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'length' => $flights->count(),
                'results' => $flights
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried with `array_merge(table A, table B)` but it didn't work.

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert them to array, then merge them in a new array called for example `data`. Below code may help you:

```
$data=[
   'flights' => $flights->toArray(),
   'details' => $details->toArray(),
];

return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'length' => $flights->count(),
            'results' => $data
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/30524136/1529662
And your $flights and $details variables are collection. If you want to convert, you should use [toArray()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-toarray) method.

Answer (score 0):

There can be two scenarios:

1. Flight record hasOne/hasMany FlightDetail records (related)

   - flight_details table will have a foreign key flight_id
2. Flight and FlightDetail are not related

   - flight_details table doesn't have foreign key flight_id

Scenario 1

```php
//Models

class Flight extends Model
{
    public function details()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(FlightDetail::class, 'flight_id', 'id');
    }
}


class FlightDetail extends Model
{
    public function flight()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Flight::class, 'flight_id', 'id');
    }
}


class FilterController extends Controller
{
    public function product(Request $request) {

        $flights= Flight::with('details`)->get();
        if(empty($flights)) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'length' => 0,
                'error' => 'No fly found',
                'results' => []
            ]);
        }else {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'length' => $flights->count(),
                'results' => $flights
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Scenario 2

```php
class FilterController extends Controller
{
    public function product(Request $request) {

        $flights= Flight::all();
        $details = Flights_detail::all();

        if(empty($flights)) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'length' => 0,
                'error' => 'No fly found',
                'results' => []
            ]);
        }else {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'length' => [
                    'flights' => $flights->count(), 
                    'flightDetails' => $details->count()
                ],
                'results' => [
                    'flights' => $flights, 
                    'flightDetails' => $details
                ]
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```