# Laravel combine resource collection when returning response

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a resource which looks like so;

```php
class TestingResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'first' => AnotherResource::collection($this->first),
            'second' => AnotherResource::collection($this->second),
        ];
    }
}
```

What I want to do is combine the 2 so I only have to return one element like so;

```php
class TestingResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'first' => AnotherResource::collection($this->combined),
        ];
    }
}
```

I tried doing `array_merge($this->first, $this->second)` but it doesnt work.

Is there any way of getting this to work?

Comment: This will help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30522528/how-to-merge-two-eloquent-collections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`concat()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-concat) for collections like:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    $first = FirstResource::collection(First::all());
    $second = SecondResource::collection(Second::all());

    $combined = new Collection();
    return $combined->concat($first)->concat($second);
}
```

This concatenates key. The `merge()` will overwrite the values.